# How to interpret hazard ratios in Cox model in Stata?

Tags: interpretation, stata, hazard

I am estimating the survival of trade relationships from South Africa to various importing countries. These are the hazard ratios using robust standard errors. I just want to know how to interpret the results.

Is this correct?

- Value > 1 indicates higher hazard ratios (poor survival)
- Value between 0 – 1 indicates lower hazard ratios (good survival)
- Value = 1 indicates that the variable has no effect on the hazard rate (constant hazard).

For example: If SA has a common language with importing country =1 if not = 0
How to interpret 0.745 hazard ratio for this variable?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct.
For the "common language" variable, having a common language reduces the hazard to where it is 0.745 times the hazard that it would be given everything else was the same but there was no common language. The hazard measures the probability of the trade relationship ending in the near future after time t given there is a relationship up to time t. There is a lower risk of it ending if they have a common language (about 3/4 the risk compared to if they do not have a common language).

Comment: Thanks so much!!!

Comment: When you again visit CV @NicolevanderMerwe, if you think this post answered your query and clarified your prevailing confusion(s), then please upvote and [accept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the post by clicking on the tick symbol alongside it.